# XMLParser.sharedParser.decode() in swift3

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift3, nsxmlparser

I used this code  `XMLParser.sharedParser.decode()` in swift2. But I migrate swift3 this code didn't work.

My code is here,

```
func xmppStream(_ sender: XMPPStream!, didReceive message: XMPPMessage!) {


    let result1 = XMLParser.sharedParser.decode(String(message))

    for (key, value) in result1 {

        let title = result1["title"]

    }

   if message.isChatMessage(){

       sms = String(message.body())
       if( sms == "" || message.body() == nil){

       }else{
           self.prefs.set(sms, forKey: "SMS")

       }
   }

}
```

Comment: `this code didn't work` This is not very useful. Instead, please explain what are the error(s), what doesn't work, what it should do but doesn't, etc. Thanks.

Comment: Type 'XMLParser' has no member 'sharedParser' @EricAya

Comment: how to write in swift3? @EricAya

Answer (score 0):

If you are using codes from [this repo](https://github.com/Mozharovsky/XMLParser), unfortunately, it hasn't been upgraded to Swift 3.

Answer (score 0):

```
var event : DDXMLElement = message.forName("event", xmlns: "http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#event")!

            let items : [DDXMLElement] = event.elements(forName: "items")

            for i: DDXMLElement in items {

                var item  = i.elements(forName: "item")

                for j: DDXMLElement in item {
                    var xml = j.elements(forName: "xml")
                    for x : DDXMLElement in xml {
                        var about = x.elements(forName: "about")

                       debugPrint(about.cs_arrayValue().first?.stringValue)

                    }
                }

            }
```

After I added the above code, my problem is solved!